# Android : Compare two dates with different time zones

Tags: java, android, date, timezone, compare

I would like to compare two dates, which can have different time zones.

I explain, I receive data from my server (JSON) and I want to compare this data who contains date to my device local date, like Facebook (There are 2 minutes, There are 1 week, There are 3 years).

Server response : date:'2013-10-09T00:52:20+02:00'

Someone would have an idea, how I can do it ?

Comment: Normalize your dates to UTC and then compare them - don't forget to take daylight savings into consideration. There are plenty of questions here on SO which cover this subject - please search the site before asking.